# How to encapsulate ng-bind-html behavior into custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to abstract away ng-bind-html behavior from:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages >
        <p ng-bind-html=message.title ng-phone-caller="message.title"> </p> 
    </div>
```

and move it into my custom directive which takes my string input and will wrap HTML tags around the phone numbers so that it's clickable on mobile.

```
    .directive('ngPhoneCaller',function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                ngPhoneCaller: '='
            },
            link: function (scope) {
var stringWithHtmlWrapper = $sce.getTrustedHtml(wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag(scope.ngPhoneCaller));
                scope.ngPhoneCaller = $sce.trustAsHtml(stringWithHtmlWrapper);
            }
            }
        }
        });
```

so that anyone who uses my attribute directive ng-phone-caller doesn't need to also instantiate ng-bind-html. Any suggestions as to how I would achieve this? I tried utilizing $sce, but doesn't that still require me to use ng-bind-html? For example, if I didn't use ng-bind-html with $sce, I ended up with an improperly formatted message i.e) "We&# 8217;re currently unavailable.

Comment: Why don't you use `template` in directive to wrap it? Is `scope.ngPhoneCaller` just  text string? Or is it html? If it is string what you are doing is overkill when angular can do it for you

Comment: It's a string that will be updated to have a href tags around the phone number around it once its passed into the ng-phone-caller directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a filter for this? Using `$sce.trustAsHtml` will allow your use of HTML as `ng-bind-html` does.

```
.filter('phoneCaller', function($sce) {
    return function(value) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag(value));
    };
});
```

You would use this filter as:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages >
    <p ng-bind="message.title | phoneCaller"></p>
    <!-- Or alternately -->
    <p>{{ message.title | phoneCaller }}</p>
</div>
```

#### Update

If you really don't want to use `ng-bind-html` in the client code, you can give your directive a simple template and create a function in a directive controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('ngPhoneCaller', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngPhoneCaller: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.wrappedPhoneCaller = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag($scope.ngPhoneCaller));
      }
    },
    template: '<p ng-bind-html="wrappedPhoneCaller()"></p>'
  };
});
```

Your client code would then look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages >
  <div ng-phone-caller="message.title"></div>
</div>
```

Since this is calculating it on every digest cycle, you might look to cache it or set up your own `$watch` in the controller to bind to this as a normal $scope property (not a functional call).

Comment: I have, but stuck with using a directive because it includes DOM manipulation. From my understanding $sce.trustAsHtml only renders your html safe to use, but in the view if I did <p>{{ message.title | phoneCaller }}</p> it would render the string literal. I would still need to add ng-bind-html attribute for actually displaying the html properly.

Comment: I've updated this to use a directive, I believe I fully understand your requirement now. Will that work for your client code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$sce`:

```
.directive('ngPhoneCaller',function($sce) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngPhoneCaller: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var html = wrapStringWithPhoneNumberHTMLTag(scope.ngPhoneCaller);
            element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(html) || '');
        }
    }
    });
```

---

You also need to add `$watch` to affect any scope changes.

For more info about, you can read original `ngBindHtml` [implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L186-L207).

Comment: Using $sce still requires me to use ng-bind-html though, right? Please see my updated post

Comment: Wrong. `ng-bind-html` uses it, your directive uses it too. Independently.

Comment: take a look to @doxavore answer. Filter is the best solution for your task. Because it cares about any source data changes.